# How to make XPath return 'None' in Python if no data found?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

XPath returns nothing if a child element has no text value. In this case, rating has no data, so I want it to say so - None or nothing in this child instead of just ignoring it. Your input is much appreciated.

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book>  
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
  <rating></rating>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="hindi">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
  <rating></rating>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

**Python :**

```
>>> import lxml.html as lh
>>> bk=open('book.xml','r')
>>> bkout=lh.parse(bk)
>>> bk.close()
>>> bkout.xpath('//book/*/text()')
['Harry Potter', '29.99', 'Learning XML', '39.95']

>>> bkout.xpath('//book/* and not(text())/text()')
True
```

**Desired Output :**

```
['Harry Potter', '29.99', '', 'Learning XML', '39.95', '']
or
['Harry Potter', '29.99', None, 'Learning XML', '39.95', None]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the "text()":

```
In [16]: [x.text for x in bk.xpath("//book/*")]
Out[16]: ['Harry Potter', '29.99', None, 'Learning XML', '39.95', None]
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I was looking for something in XPath directly instead of a for loop but may be not. I will stick to this way of doing it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with <span> tags or other tags with attributes. For instance, <span class="brightred">Hello</span> ==> [x.text for x in bk.xpath(""//book/span[@class="brightred"]/*)]. If there are multiple span tags, it doesn't work. Shall I modify the questin or open a new question? I want to avoid redundancy! Thank you!

Comment: I think you should remove the "/*" at the end of your xpath. In the answer I gave you on Jun19th the * matched with <title>,<price> and <rating>. Here you are trying to match any tag inside <span> but there is none of them.. there's just a text node inside, which doesn't match the *.