# How to make XPath return 'None' in Python if no attribute found?

Tags: python, xml, attributes, lxml

This is a kind of add-on to an earlier question [asking the same things for the text values in an XML node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105900).

lxml can test the existence of a tag by an XPath (e.g. `//book/*`) in the referred example. 
With this I can test the existence of the node and return `None` if it is not present and return the text value if it exists.

However, it seems that you cannot just test for an attribute in the same way, as e.g. `//book/@author` would directly return a list with the values of the author attribute in all books, but without `None`, just a shorter list.

Is there a way to get back a list with all authors that has Nones in it when there is no author attribute given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such construct in XPath.

You can perform this in two steps:

1. Get all book elements with XPath, as you currently do (eg. `//book/*`)
2. Iterate those elements and check if each of them has an author attribute (eg. `book.get('author')` or `if 'author' in book.attrib:`)

Comment: Or list comprehension: `[book if 'author' in book.attrib else None for book in data.xpath('//book/*')]`

Answer (score 1):

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<books>
<book author="1">Johnny Dape</book>
<book >Al Pacino</book>
<book author="3">Robert De Niro</book>
<book author="4">Kevin Spacey</book>
<book >Denzel Washington</book>
</books>

</root>'''

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
[book.get('author', None)  for book in tree.xpath('//book')]
```

out:

```
['1', None, '3', '4', None]
```

Xpath is all about evalue the location step, anything is evalued 'None' will not show in the result list.

But the tag's attrubute is stored in python dict object, you can use `dict.get('attr', None)` to return a None value if the attribute does not exist.