# Need Xpath to return a empty list item when parsing an html file

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, xpath

I am using xpath to parse a table with about 761 items.  The table has about 10 attributes.  In the end, I want to create a CSV file so I can load the table into excel.

I am able to load the local HTML file with:

```
with open('test.html','r') as f:
    page = f.read()
tree = html.fromstring(page)
```

The table is constructed using divs.  here would be an example of two records:

```
<div ...>
   <a href = '.../office/profile'>Office 1</a>
</div>
<div ...>
   <a href = '.../office/profile'>Office 2</a>
</div>
<div class='data-table-cell-3'>
   <span><span>Contact 1</span></span>
</div>
<div class='data-table-cell-3'>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

I am able to parse both Office 1 and Office 2 with this:

```
office = tree.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/office/profile')]/text()")
```

and I get a list with two elements!

When I go to parse the contacts with this:

```
contact_name = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'data-table-cell-3')]/span/span/text()")
```

I get a list that is [Contact 1] rather than ['Contact 1', ''].  NOTE THE HTML STRUCTURE CHANGES A BIT HERE AND TAKES OUT THE SPAN.

I have read this post: [How to make XPath return 'None' in Python if no data found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105900/how-to-make-xpath-return-none-in-python-if-no-data-found)

and tried to implement it as follows:

```
contact_name = [x.text for x in tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'data-table-cell-3')]/span/span/text()")]
```

and as:

```
contact_name = [x.text for x in tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'data-table-cell-3')]/span/span")]
```

and neither returned an array with ['Contact 1', none]

Comment: In XPath at least to version 2.0, you can only select nodes. Yo might get an empty sequence or node set as the result of your selection, but you cannot get a non empty sequece or node set and an empty one from the same expression. You need to iterate over one first result with your host language and then get the values you want within each context, including the non existing ones.

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of 1,0 for what each node returns or trues and false?  Then I could map the data.

Comment: FYI `contact_name = tree.xpath("//div[@class='data-table-cell-3']/descendant::*[last()]/text()")` will return `['Contact 1', '\xa0']` as output.

Comment: This is perfect want to add it as an answer and I can accept it @supputuri

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath.

```
 contact_name = tree.xpath("//div[@class='data-table-cell-3']/descendant::*[last()]/text()")
```

**output:**

> ['Contact 1', '\xa0']